Python+SQLAlchemy - Working with memory usage for in-memory database
I have a Flask application with a database that looks like
class Talk(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'talk'

    talkId = db.Column(db.String, primary_key=True)
    _id = db.Column(db.String)
    talkName = db.Column(db.String)
    talkOrigin = db.Column(db.String)

where db is
db = SQLAlchemy()

The db is initialized at app start-up with the uri
'sqlite://'

To this table I add/modify/records at around 1500 operations a second for a few seconds, followed by a minute of inactivity and then 1500 operations again for a few seconds. It appears that this application ramps up to 150 mb of memory at a steady state when I'm transacting, and then levels off at 150 mb and stays there even when the table is empty. This in itself is not a big concern because I have plenty of memory left, but I'm trying to understand why this chunk of memory stays at that size. From what I can read it appears that this memory is allocated as needed to store new records, but not released back to the OS because it might be needed again (unless I run vacuum?)
Can I limit how much memory the database gets to use? Is there a way to reclaim memory more proactively? I've seen 2 recommendations

run gc.collect()

run sqlite vacuum/vacuum+analyze



Does this answer your question?

Thanks @snakecharmerb yeah it's one of the areas I'm looking at. I'll add some debug and see if I get which direction I need to go in
